# ModX Evo: user was deleted whilst editing a resource. Cannot access resource

Tags: session, content-management-system, modx, modx-evolution

A client of mine deleted a user whilst they were editing a resource. The user is gone but the resource is still locked out of other users ("User X is editing this document...).

I have tried clearing the cache to no effect.

Does anyone know a way of removing this users session? Is there something I must remove in the database via PHPMyAdmin?

Answer (score 0):

Had a look in the DB. Removed the user from the table `modx_active_users` and it seems to have worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try Removing Locks. It was made for these kind of weird situations.

`Tools` -> `Remove Locks`